# What is the first string in Java from a lexicographical comparison perspective?

Tags: java

I am using the String.compareTo() method for String comparison.

Consider the following code:

```
String firstLexicon = "0"; 
String anyString = "anyString";
int result = firstLexicon.compareTo(anyString);
```

What would be the value for `firstLexicon` so that the method `firstLexicon.compareTo(anyString);` will always give a negative result for any value except `firstLexicon`? 
My best guess was `"0"`.

Comment: It can't always give a negative result. At least `firstLexicon.compareTo(firstLexicon);` will return 0 for any value of `firstLexicon`.

Comment: Could you give us a bigger context? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe `""` could work ok for you?

Comment: `""` Might be an option. The context is that this value will be used as a start key in HBase, for a reserve scan. What would be the result of `"".compareTo("0");` ?

Comment: or `"\0"` / `'\0'` (which is a `char` with with value 0, not the character for 0.). It's the next string after `""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty string (`""`) is smaller than any other string since the first `min(firstLexicon.length(), anyString.length())` (`=0`) are compared and if that doesn't yield a difference, the shorter `String` is the lexicographical smaller string.

Answer (score 0):

firstLexicon should be 0 to achieve what you want, with just one exception, comparing "0" to itself will return a 0

Edit: I was wrong, the correct answer is the empty string ""

Comment: `"0".compareTo("")` returns 1.